# React Materialize Carousel Autoplay

Tags: reactjs, carousel, materialize, autoplay

Given the code below, I would like to make the carousel autoplay within the said interval. However, being new in React, I have no idea on how to do it. I have tried searching for answers and have tried using carousel('next'), it didn't work. I am still finding answers and is hoping to clear this problem. Thanks!

```
import React from 'react';
import { Carousel } from 'react-materialize';

const Header = () => {
const imgArr = [
'https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0',
'https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=1',
'https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=2',
];

return (
<Carousel
  className='tabs'
  options={{ duration: 100, indicators: true }}
  images={imgArr}
/>
);
);
```

Comment: You can do this without using react-materialize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this plugin instead: http://www.linxtion.com/demo/react-image-gallery/

You can use the prop slideInterval to decide when the next slide will occur.

Comment: Hi, Nico. I have read the docs and how to install the ImageGallery component, it is working. Tho, I would like to follow-up if there is a way that Carousel component can play? Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/xiaolin/react-image-gallery#props autoPlay: Boolean, default false; set autoPlay to true